# What's the point of having continuation opcode?

Tags: websocket

Here's an example from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets/Writing_WebSocket_servers):

```
Client: FIN=1, opcode=0x1, msg="hello"
Server: (process complete message immediately) Hi.
Client: FIN=0, opcode=0x1, msg="and a"
Server: (listening, new message containing text started)
Client: FIN=0, opcode=0x0, msg="happy new"
Server: (listening, payload concatenated to previous message)
Client: FIN=1, opcode=0x0, msg="year!"
Server: (process complete message) Happy new year to you too!
```

Isn't the FIN bit enough to determine whether the message is finished or to be continued? The continuation opcode looks to be redundant to me.

Answer (score 1):

The opt codes indicate the type of frame. Only the first frame can indicate if it is Text (0x1) or Binary, and control frames cannot be fragmented, so the ausence of any opt code (0x0) means Continuation.

I mean, if you have 4 bits available and you want to send nothing, you put all zeroes (0x0), but you still need to send those four bits.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.2